# Query JPQL para retornar somente um dos campos

Tags: java, jpql

Estou tentando criar uma consulta para retorna somente o nome, porém o JPQL não reconhece o comando select como podem ver no código abaixo.

```
@Repository
public class NumeroVotosMembroRepositoryImpl implements NumeroVotosMembroRepositoryQuery{
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public List<NumeroVotosMembro> ListarNumeros() {
        TypedQuery<NumeroVotosMembro>  consulta = manager.createQuery("select nvm.nome FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", NumeroVotosMembro.class);
        return consulta.getResultList();
    }
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente quando é para retornar todos os campos da entidade.

```
TypedQuery<NumeroVotosMembro>  consulta = manager.createQuery("FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", NumeroVotosMembro.class);
```

Como poderia corrigir o código para o JPQL retornar apenas o nome?

Comment: Se vc só quer o nome, então o retorno não pode ser `NumeroVotosMembro`, e sim o tipo do nome - supondo que seja `String`, deveria ser `manager.createQuery("select nvm.nome FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", String.class)` (e claro, o retorno do método deve ser `List<String>`, a query é `TypedQuery<String>`, etc)

Comment: Outra opção é criar um objeto customizado que só tem os campos que vc quer, ou então o mais genérico, `Object[]`, algo [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24710626). Mas como no seu caso só tem um campo, talvez seja mais simples só trazer a `String` mesmo

Comment: @hkotsubo funcionou perfeitamente, se quiser pode colocar sua resposta para eu marca-la como certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro do [método `createQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) indica qual o tipo de dado que será retornado.

Quando você faz o `SELECT` pela entidade inteira, aí funciona, afinal você indicou que o retorno da query é `NumeroVotosMembro`.

Mas quando a query só retorna um dos campos, aí o tipo dela não é mais `NumeroVotosMembro`. Em vez disso, o retorno será apenas o campo, portanto o tipo deve ser o mesmo do campo sendo retornado.

Por exemplo, se o nome for uma `String`, basta mudar a query para retornar este tipo:

```java
// troque NumeroVotosMembro por String
@Override
public List<String> ListarNumeros() {
    TypedQuery<String> consulta = manager.createQuery("select nvm.nome FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", String.class);
    return consulta.getResultList();
}
```

**Obs:** talvez o nome do método devesse ser `listarNomes`?

---

De forma geral, quando você não quer todos os campos da entidade, outra opção é retornar cada registro como um array de `Object`:

```java
// selecionando o ID e NOME
TypedQuery<Object[]> consulta = manager.createQuery("select nvm.id, nvm.nome FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", Object[].class);
List<Object[]> resultados = consulta.getResultList();
for (Object[] linha : resultados) {
    System.out.println("id=" + linha[0] + ", nome=" + linha[1]);
}
```

Ou então você pode criar uma classe customizada que só contém os campos que você quer:

```java
public class CustomObject {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    public CustomObject(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    // getters, etc...
}

// e na query você retorna o CustomObject
TypedQuery<CustomObject> consulta = manager.createQuery("select NEW CustomObject(nvm.id, nvm.nome) FROM NumeroVotosMembro nvm", CustomObject.class);
List<CustomObject> resultados = consulta.getResultList();
```

---

Mas no seu caso, como só tem um campo, a primeira opção acima é mais simples.